# Text type column showing filter as number type

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am generating excel file in laravel using maatwebsite.And set A column as text format and applied filter on it. When excel generate with any numeric data it shows filter sorting witth option lowest to highest and highest to lower.In case of text data showing filter sorting with option A to Z and Z to A.Now my question is when numeric data stored as text datatype filter sorting also should be A to z and Z to A option.

```
 $sheet->getStyle($range)
       ->getNumberFormat()
       ->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
```

Comment: Any one have an idea As we are using number stored as text in excel how I can do this with laravel excel.I think this way I ll got my solution.